Laravel 11 creating route with 2 models injected
I have the following Laravel 11 controller method and route:
Route::prefix('g/{guide:slug}/p/{property:slug}') // Use "slug" constraint for parameters
->controller(GuestController::class)
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'guidePropertyBySlug')
            ->where('guide', Guide::class)  // Use model class for type hinting
            ->where('property', Property::class)
            ->name('guide-property-slug.show')
            ->withoutScopedBindings();
    });


public function guidePropertyBySlug(Guide $guide, Property $property): Response|ResponseFactory
{
    $guideProperty = GuideProperty::where('guide_id', $guide->id)->where('property_id', $property->id)->firstOrFail();
    $guideProperty->load( 'guide.featuredMedia', 'guide.categories.featuredMedia', 'guide.categories.tileFeaturedMedia', 'property.address', 'property.hotel.address', 'property.description', 'property.featuredMedia');

    return $this->setData($guideProperty)->send();
}

In both my Guide and Property models I have 2 Traits:
Uuidable which sets getRouteKeyName to uuid
Sluggable which does not have a getRouteKeyName set, and uses column slug
This code gives the following error:
2024-04-07 22:37:37] local.ERROR: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character follows \ at offset 18 {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): preg_match(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character follows \\ at offset 18 at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Matching/UriValidator.php:21)
[stacktrace]

I have tried various combinations already without success. How do I get the route working where both Guide and Property get resolved via their slugs?

Okay so there's a few problems here.
Resolving the model
The dependency injection is handled by Laravel automatically and you don't need to do anything to resolve these dependencies. Laravel is smart enough to perform this query for you automatically, they name it Implicit Binding.
Laravel's documentation has an example of using the slug as a parameter and it automatically resolving without any configuration or code needed for it to work. You can see that here: Routing - Customizing the key
Using Where
We're then also using the Where method on the routes. I can see where this confusion came from as it has the same name as the method commonly used on a Query Builder. However, the where method on routes is a method that allows you to place Regular Expression Constraints on the parameter, rather than being used to build a query to get the Model based on some values passed in the URL.
The where method on routes is for ensuring the route parameter matches a certain pattern so you can validate the request is valid, almost like a validation rule for routes. An example would be enforcing the {user} property on the route to be an ID.
Note: It doesn't change the dependency resolution or have any other effects on how you implement resolution etc.
Unnecessary Nested Route Group
After that you seem to have registered a Group of routes, and nested another inside it. This nested group is just the root directory of it's parent and I don't believe this serves any purpose but makes the code look more confusing.
Solution
Here's an example after we've resolved the problems above
Route::get('g/{guide:slug}/p/{property:slug}', [GuestController::class, 'guidePropertyBySlug'])
    ->name('guide-property-slug.show')
    ->withoutScopedBindings();

Extra Advice
I'm not perfect and I'm learning myself and I understand the struggle, but I'd also move your functionality out of GuestController if Guest Controller has multiple responsibilities, or at least name the class in a way that better describes it's job.
Due to how things are named it gives me the impression that the controller for guests is doing more than it should be. You should probably move the logic for that into a controller that is made with that sole purpose.
If my assumptions are correct making these changes should improve the quality of the codebase as classes will have a name that more clearly identifies what their purpose is for. Your code will also be separated so you have seperation of concerns.
Essentially, you wont have one big file doing a ton of different things. You won't have an unclear structure to your code base and it will be obvious where to find where your functionality is placed. You'll be able to be adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle too which is a part of the SOLID principles I'd recommend looking into and implementing over time as you learn and progress as it's extremely important to writing good code and making good stuff.

Hi Dylan Thank you so much for your answer. My issue is I cannot set getRouteKeyName  in my Sluggable trait as it is in use in Uuidable.

Is the sluggable trait a custom implementation or from a package?

I'm back, I don't believe the getRouteKeyName over-writes all Route Keys you specify manually, it only specifies the default route key name if you don't want to use the default behaviour.
Because we're specifying we want the 'slug' and it's a property that exists on the model {guide:slug} this should just work with the way I've proposed I believe unless you have any extra context.

Yeah I've just checked this is working on Laravel 11 on a fresh install. The error is mainly due to the fact that you've specified this regular expression:
        ->where('guide', Guide::class)  // Use model class for type hinting
        ->where('property', Property::class)

That's not Regex. You still need to fix the rest of the issues with your code that I've documented above.
